# Observable from store.select doesn't seem to have updated values

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an `ApplicationState` which has `project` member and my `ProjectState` is something like this:

```
interface ProjectState {
   listObjs: SomeType[];
}
```

In my `component.ts` onInit I have something like this:

```
...
this.objID = someString
...

this.listObj$ = 
this.store.select( state => state.project.listObjs.find( item => item.id === this.objID));
...
```

In my reducer I am handling creation of new state like this:

```
...
case (action.ACTION1): {

    const newState = {... state};
    const objIndex = state.listObjs.findIndex( item => item.id === action.payload.id )

    if ( objIndex === -1 ) {
        return state;
    }

    Object.assign(newState.listObjs[objIndex].someMember, {... action.payload.someData});

    return newState;
}
...
```

I subscribed to `listObj$` in my component onInit, but it gets served when initializing and whenever I make changes to `obj` in array I don't see the `subscribe` getting updated data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "direct" state mutation.

The spread operator (`...`) does not clone recursive and `Object.assign` mutates `newState.listObjs[objIndex].someMember`.

You can install ngrx-store-freeze or enable the runtime checks in ngrx v8, and you'll get an error that you can't modify the state like this.

To solve this issue, you'll have to create a new state in an immutable way, or use immer.
[Clean NgRx reducers using Immer](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/clean-ngrx-reducers-using-immer)

Comment: using `immer` was very easy and it solved my issue. Without using `immer` I was able to solve the same issue using  `ngrx/entity`. Thanks for pointing out `ngrx-store-freeze`. It is helping me to identify bugs during development and I am able to change my component's `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush`

Comment:  in NgRx 8 we have a baked-in ngrx-store-freeze called runtime checks. See https://medium.com/ngrx/announcing-ngrx-version-8-ngrx-data-create-functions-runtime-checks-and-mock-selectors-a44fac112627 for more info.If you're liking Immer, you will also like https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-etc#readme (which is for NgRx 8)